In R, how and where does the underlying C functions get their argument inputs?
I'm trying to understand what happens at the C level when I call a function in R. For instance, print("Hello, World!") will call UseMethod("print"). From the "table" in names.c, line 832, I know that UseMethod() in turn will call do_usemethod:
{"UseMethod",   do_usemethod,   0,     200, -1, {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},

I have a basic understanding of what the columns mean, but when I look at the code for do_usemethod, in objects.c on line 538, I get confused:
/* This is a primitive SPECIALSXP */
attribute_hidden NORET
SEXP do_usemethod(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
{ 
    ...
}

Can someone explain how and where do_usemethod picks up the input arguments? I guess op could be the arity column in names.c, but what about call, args and env? The answer may be obvious, but I find it very difficult to follow the breadcrumbs here, and I have been at it for weeks.
I have read the help for UseMethod() and also started reading Appendix A of Statistical Models in S (Chambers & Hastie, 1992), but did not find an answer to my question. I don't know of any books that go more into details.

call is the R call; args is a pairlist of promises (in this case, unevaluated "supplied" arguments not yet matched to a pairlist of "formal" arguments to produce a pairlist of "actual" arguments); env is the calling environment where the promises are often (but not always) evaluated.  typeof(UseMethod) == "special" and specials are partly documented in the R Internals manual, which you didn't mention.

Thanks, I had (another) look at R Internals and found some useful information, some of which I've read before but forgotten; I've been at it for a while. But I still find it difficult to track in the actual code. Maybe its the wrong way to think about it, but in my head args, env etc must be created at some point, or am I wrong here? Right now I'm going through eval.c, deparse.c, and so on, trying to find clues.

eval(e, rho) does something like PRIMFUN(op) (e, op, CDR(e), rho) for calls e to special op.  The args are just e without the first element.  How e and rho are originally formed depends on the caller of eval.  eval is called "everywhere" (in the REPL, in eval itself (recursively), in user code (since eval is API)) so there is no singular answer to your question.

My original question that prompted this was "what happens when I type print("Hello, World!") and hit enter from the R console?" So I guess any evaluation talking place as a consequence of that is what I'm after. I found tracking down each function call and where/how their arguments are formed fairly straightforward, apart from the initial UseMethod and .Internal calls. I wanted to learn more about R's inner workings, but underestimated the complexity of such a "simple" question.

R has both functions and methods(S3 or S4); in this case print is a method (S3 type I believe), the input value is going to be scanned for the class of its input, and a special case for print wont be found so ultimately the useMethod process will identify it should call print.default() function. which itself will make a call to a compiled C function  .Internal(print.default(x, args, missings))

Thanks, I already figured that part out. I want to understand in detail where and how the C level functions get their argument input. print.default will call the C level function do_printdefault, defined in print.c on line 220. How are the arguments from print.default (x, args, missings) "translated" into the arguments for do_printdefault (SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP rho)?

Have you read Writing R Extensions and its chapters on the C API ?

I've frantically searched it, yes. I had another go, and Section 5.9 covers calls via .C and .External (but not .Internal). A call to the latter, e.g. .External("convolveE", a, b), seems to have a C interface similar to what (I think) I'm after; SEXP convolveE(SEXP args), where args is a Lisp-style pairlist, LISTSXP. But I still cannot figure out how and where a and b end up in args.

I think you would benefit from taking a step back, pretending that .Internal() did not exist and see what you can with .Call().  Things will get easier.  In C you still have a lot of manual unpacking to do, some of the higher-level packages for extending R can help with that,

Yeah, my C skills are definitely lacking, unfortunately. This is me skipping ahead several steps. I'll delve into .Call() for a while. Thanks.
